# Why won't my iPad sync photos ("not enough memory") when it's half empty?

Tags: ios, ipad, data-synchronization

When I try to sync my iPad, it aborts on the last step, indicating that it can't be synced, becuase "not enough memory is available":

[image]

But I have LOTS of room:

[image]

And it all fit before - I actually have about 8GB of photos that all fit with  ~20GB to spare until today.   The above image is after I set it to only sync the last 20 photo projects (I'm using aperture) to see if space was really an issue, and it's clearly not.

However, photos *do* seem to be a part of the problem:   **if i turn off photo sync, it works, but if I reduce the photos being synced (sunk? syunk?) to a de minimis number, it doesn't.**

The catalyst for the problem is pretty likely either the new version of itunes or of OSX, as both were upgraded just before the problem manifested.  Any help?  I miss my pictures.

Comment: There is a bug in 10.3 and lower where if you select "compress songs" to save space on the iOS device - it makes bad guesses on the free space. I don't think it's the cause with such a HUGE gap - but worth a shot.

Comment: @bmike, I'm assuming the toggle you're referencing is "convert higher bit rate songs to 128 kbps AAC"?  If so, that's not it - I've never had it on.

Comment: Bummer. That's the switch that drives me nuts on my 14G iPhone. I'm ready to move my music to the cloud :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had iTunes go off the deep end thinking there were far too many photos.

I have had luck with several tacks so I presume there are a few bugs - one of which you may have run into:

1. Take the device to another computer (or another iTunes library on a shell account) and let it sync and erase all photos on iOS. Taking it back to the main iTunes library which has the correct photos sometimes works. I presume the error was an accounting one on the iPad when this works.
2. Change photo sync to a simple folder with a jpeg or two, sync it, and then change back to the settings I prefer. (rarely works)
3. Rebuild the affected library in Aperture or iPhoto - this seems to force new data into the media browser so iTunes is forced to take a better look at the sizes for your albums and photos as organized.

Sorry I don't have a sure fire answer - but maybe you haven't tried all of these or it sparks an idea of something else you can try.

Comment: save your sorry - #3 did the trick.   The key was repairing the library and permissions in Aperture.  If #1 and #2 never caused *this* error for you, you may want to edit your response to focus on #3 and explain how to do it, for folks who don't know:  In Aperture, you open the app while holding option and command down to bring up the repair menu.  (I don't know the iphoto equivalent.)

Comment: Oh - 1 and 2 have hit me on many occasions (but mostly when running beta OS or iTunes come to think of it). I added them first since they can be faster and have helped others often. I'm happy now!

Comment: i had the same problem with my photos library and my iphone. here is a [link](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204967) for how to repair your library (in 2020)

Answer (score -1):

Okay I Had the same problem when I tried syncing my music on my Iphone I did some messing around with my itunes and I finally found the way to fix it and what I did was unselected evrything that I wanted to sync to my phone basically did a blank sync between my phone and computer which I guess let itunes know what was on my phone and what was on the computer because after I had done that I resulected what I wanted to sync and it worked perfect. Hopes this helps because I spent hours trying to find a solution on the internet and nothing worked.